# Why is Windows form control click event being fired before form shown event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form that instantiates and opens another form. It was working fine until recently, while re-purposing the second form that the click event on a Radio Button on the form has started being fired after form load. I have code in the form.shown event but it is never called (the form crashes during the radio button click event, as it is not supposed to be called so soon). The call stack window suggests that a PictureBox click event is also being fired right before or after the RadioButton click event.

Form Load:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblCountdown.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    lblCountdown.Font = New Font(lblCountdown.Font.Name, lblCountdown.Font.Size + 10, lblCountdown.Font.Style)

    radFirstRunContinue.Checked = False
    radFirstRunContinue.Visible = False

    For Each picBox As PictureBox In tlpButtonTableLayout.Controls
        AddHandler picBox.Click, AddressOf Me.PictureBox_click
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not have enough rep to post an image of the call stack window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes form controls will fire when the form is initialized. This might sound like a bug, but Microsoft calls it "by design".

1. Check and make sure only one instance of the form is being loaded. If you access a variable or control in the form from outside, it will initiate an implicit form load. To check this, just set a breakpoint at the beginning of the Load event handler.
2. You can use a flag (initialized to true, for example) that control handlers can use to see the form is being loaded. You can reset the flag in the form Shown event.

Comment: Huh, well that's odd. I had never heard of that. Is it random or will these events always fire if I don't change the form again?

Comment: I'm not sure. They seem to fire consistently until use a flag in to prevent the handler execution, and then I forget about it. But it seems to be random from project to project. Another solution is to assign the event handler after form initialization, but I think that would be a little confusing in future maintenance.

Comment: @TravelinMax - In regard to point 1 by xpda, you should _never_ use the default Form instances.  When using a form, you should always be doing something like this:  `Dim frm As New Form1 ... frm.Show() etc.`  If you find yourself just using the name of your form class with `Show` or `ShowDialog` then you are using default form instances, which should be avoided.  They are a carry over from VB6 for compatibility purposes.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes my form1 is the default form (the one that loads when the program is opened) and it instantiates a new form2 then displays it.